# My onchange event is not firing! Unsure of why

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to change the `.innerText` property of the first `a` if the selected value of the `option` is `1` I'm not seeing any errors in the console and have tried moving my script around to see if that changes anything, but it doesn't. Right now my script is at the end of the body.

why isn't this working?!

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L2gm9/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <ol>
        <li><a href="#">This is the first link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is the first link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is the first link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is the first link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is the first link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is the first link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is the first link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is the first link</a></li>
    </ol>
    <select id="numbers">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option value=1>1</option>
        <option value=2>2</option>
        <option value=3>3</option>
        <option value=4>4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    var select = document.getElementById("element"),
        option = select.firstElementChild; 


    select.addEventListener("onchange", function(){

            var div = document.getElementById("hook"),
                ol = div.firstElementChild,
                li = ol.firstElementChild,
                a = li.firstElementChild;   

            console.log(a);

            if(select.children[1].innerText === 1)
                  a.innerText = "This is the first element";
    }, false);

})();
```

Comment: `select` will be undefined because your function is being [immediately invoked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), you should just create a normal function and assign it to your `onload` event `window.onload = function() { ... }`.

Comment: @Terry: But it's at the end of the body, wouldn't that not matter?

Comment: Nevermind, you're probably looking at the fiddle. In my real example its in the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looking at the fiddle and your console, you will see the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstElementChild' of null`

The error is caused by calling the function before the element is loaded on the page.

```
window.onload = (function(){

    "use strict";

    var select = document.getElementById("element"),
        option = select.firstElementChild; 

    select.addEventListener("onchange", function(){

            var div = document.getElementById("hook"),
                ol = div.firstElementChild,
                li = ol.firstElementChild,
                a = li.firstElementChild;   
                console.log(a);

            if(this.children[0].value === 1)
                  a.innerHTML = "This is the first element";
    }, true);


})();  <-- executes the function and assigns result to unload handler
```

You want to remove the `()`

Now the next issue is you are using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) wrong. You do not use 
"on" in the event name. Also not all browsers support it.

```
select.addEventListener("change", function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making an actual javascript function and then adding the onchange attribute to the elements in the html:

```
function ChangeText() {
  var div = document.getElementById("hook"),
  ol = div.firstElementChild,
  li = ol.firstElementChild,
  a = li.firstElementChild;   

  console.log(a);

  if(select.children[1].innerText === 1) {
    a.innerText = "This is the first element";
  }
}

<select id="numbers" onchange="ChangeText();">...</select>
```

You might be better off changing the function too, to simplify it, but hopefully this points you in the right direction and solves your immediate problem.